# Is it possible to find current JUnitParams parameters from a custom rule?

Tags: junit4, junit-rule, junitparams

I started using JUnitParams to write parameterized tests and it works awesome. For example, the following test is invoked with `false`, then with `true`:

```
@Test
@Parameters ({ "false", "true" })
public void testBla (boolean foo) throws Exception
...
```

One minor trouble is that I have a custom rule (as in `org.junit.rules.TestRule`) that only exists to write some additional information to the logs. What it currently does is

```
public Statement apply (final Statement statement, final Description description)
{
    return new Statement ()
        {
            public void evaluate () throws Throwable
            {
                log.info (String.format ("RUNNING TEST %s::%s\n",
                                         description.getClassName (),
                                         description.getMethodName ()));
                ...
```

When I have just two parameters as above, it is not a problem that it writes the same name for two executions of one method, I can simply count. However, it would still be useful for the rule to print parameter values, especially if I have more.

So, is it possible to find test parameters from within a custom rule?

Answer (score 0):

**my best guess:** most parameterized junit plugins using junit's `Description` object. you should be able to get this object in your rule. but what is in this object and is it enough for your purpose depends on the specific plugin you use. if this one is not good for you, try others